# 3 dynamic combobox use php and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Need help...

How if I want to make 3 select options use jquery,

1. Parent
2. Child
3. Grandchild

Can anyone help? 
I will appreciate your help...

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $parentQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE parent = 0 ORDER BY nama_kategori");
    $kategori = ((isset($_POST['parent']) && !empty($_POST['parent']))?sanitize($_POST['parent']):'');
?>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="parent">Kategori 1:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="parent" name="parent">
        <option value="" <?php echo (($kategori =='')?'selected':''); ?>> Select</option>
        <?php while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentQuery)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $p['id_kategori'];?>" <?php echo (($kategori == $p['id_kategori'])?'selected=':''); ?>>
            <?php echo $p['nama_kategori'];?>
        </option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="child">Kategori 2:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="child" id="child"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="child">Kategori 3:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="grandchild" id="grandchild"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Use ajax....  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Comment: thanks bro.... wkwkwkwk